# Express purpose

Tags: grammar

The Article 1 in the document was written with the express purpose of obligating the UN to "encourage human rights without distinction as to race".

What does "express purpose" exactly means? For me it sounds like two nouns are paralleled which makes it seem grammatically wrong. Can't we just get rid of the word "express"?

Comment: Its an idiom, meaning "for the specific reason". What it was meant to accomplish, as opposed to other reasons.

Comment: See the definition of [Express as an adjective](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/express), #2b.  Also see [this definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/learner-english/express_2).